# Regex for custom decimal and thousand separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the below regex the handle the custom thousand separator which could be any of the `,` or `.` or `space` character which works for the thousand separator and not for the decimal indicator.

I am trying to add a new capturing group to handle decimal indicator (`,` or `.`) with maximum 2 decimals but the regex breaks for thousand separator with it.

```
^[+]?(?:\d{1,3}(?:(,|.| )\d{3})*|\d+)?,?$
```

How to add a capturing group to handle decimal with custom character? Any Ideas?

Valid Inputs:

```
1234
123.45
123,45
1234.56
1234,56
123
1,234
12,345
1,234,567
12,345,678
123,456,789

12
1.234
12.345
1.234.567
12.345.678
123.456.789

123
1 234
12 345
123 456
1 234 567
12 345 678
123 456 789

123.4567
123,4567

1,345.67
1.345,67
1 345.67

12,345.67
12.345,67
12 345.67
123,456,789.34
123.456.789,34
123 456 789.34
```

Not Valid:

```
12.345.67
12,345,67
12 345 67
123 456 789 34
```

Comment: How is `123 45` valid if `space` can not be decimal indicator?

Comment: @Asocia, Corrected...

Comment: Why is `123 4567` valid? as well as `123.4567` and `123,4567`

Comment: How about [this](https://regex101.com/r/7vFjhr/1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your specification is ambiguous, as accepting the decimal indicator as `','` you are allowing to parse `123,456` as the number `123456` or as the number `123.456` (one thousandth of it)?  If you fix the ambiguity disallowing **only** a number of three decimals, you solve the ambiguity, but at a high cost, you need the user to understand that if he makes the mistake of using three decimals, he/she will obtain weird results under strange conditions (`123,456` will be parsed as `123456.0` while `123,4560`will do as `123.456`)  This is weird for a user to accept.  It's more interesting to use the condition that a single `,` or `.` means a decimal point, while if you have both indicators, the first will be a group separator, while the second will be a decimal point.

IMHO I should never use the space as a decimal indicator (if using it as a group separator, just use it as the **only** digit group separator ---some programming languages e.g. Java, allow for `_` to be used as a digit group separator),  just nobody uses it.  It's preferable to use no decimal indicator at all (making the number an integer, scaled 10, 100, or 1000 times, this has been used for long in desktop calculators) as quick data input people prefer to key the extra zeros, than to move the finger to locate de decimal point and then type two more digits for the most of the times.  Don't say then if he has to go to the letters keyboard to find the space bar. (well, of course it is more difficult to go there to find the underscore `_` char, but quick typers don't use group separators)

In other side, people normally don't key the thousands separators, but just for readability (the computers do it in printing, but never on reading).  In this scenario, sometimes they want not the rigid situation of having groups of three digits, but to use them arbitrarily.  This leads to some situations where the user wants to separate digits in groups of three left of the decimal point, while using groups of five or ten one the right (which is something you don't contemplate at all) making, e.g. PI to appear as:

```
3.14159 26535 89793 23846 264338 3
```

I agree that using the alternate decimal point as group separator could be interesting, but at both sides of the actual decimal point, and never forcing groups of three.

Anyway, just to fit on your specs, I've written the following `lex(1)` specification to parse your input.

```
pfx     [1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?
grp     [0-9][0-9][0-9]
dec     [0-9]*

e1      [+-]?{pfx}([.]{grp})*([,]{dec})?
e2      [+-]?{pfx}([,]{grp})*([.]{dec})?
e3      [+-]?{pfx}([ ]{grp})*([.,]{dec})?
e4      [+-]?[1-9][0-9]*([,.]{dec})?
e5      [+-]?0?([,.]{dec})?
%%
{e1}|{e2}|{e3}|{e4}|{e5}            printf("\033[32m[%s]\033[m\n", yytext);
[0-9., +-]*                         printf("\033[31m[%s]\033[m\n", yytext);
.                                   |
\n                                  |
\t                                  ;
%%
int main()
{
    yylex();
}

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Your regular expression, complete, should be something like:

```
[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}([ ][0-9]{3})*([,.]([0-9]{3}[ ])*[0-9]{1,3})?|[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}([ ][0-9]{3})*([,.][0-9]{0,2})?|[+-]?[0-9]{0,2}[,.]([0-9]{3}[ ])*[0-9]{1,3}|[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}([,][0-9]{3})*([.]([0-9]{3}[,])*[0-9]{1,3})?|[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}([,][0-9]{3})*([.][0-9]{0,2})?|[+-]?[0-9]{0,2}[.]([0-9]{3}[,])*[0-9]{1,3}|[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9]{3})*([,]([0-9]{3}[.])*[0-9]{1,3})?|[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9]{3})*([,][0-9]{0,2})?|[+-]?[0-9]{0,2}[,]([0-9]{3}[.])*[0-9]{1,3}|[+-]?[0-9]*[,.][0-9]+|[+-]?[0-9]+[,.][0-9]*|[+-]?[0-9]+
```

## Note

Some regexp libraries, don't implement correctly the `|` operator, making it not actually conmutative as it should be (the worst case I know is regex101.com, see below), and forcing you to put the operands in some particular order to match some strings (this is a bug in the library, but unfortunately, this is spread)  Below is the above (which works fine with `sed(1)`) and you'll see how it [doesn't match correctly in reg101](https://regex101.com/r/6IR1Ew/2/) (There should be far less matches).

I've written also a bash script (shown below) to use `sed(1)` with the above regexp, so you can see how it works at your site:

```
dig="[0-9]"

af0="${dig}{0,2}"
af1="${dig}{1,3}"
grp="${dig}{3}"

t01="[+-]?${af1}([ ]${grp})*([,.](${grp}[ ])*${af1})?"
t02="[+-]?${af1}([ ]${grp})*([,.]${af0})?"
t03="[+-]?${af0}[,.](${grp}[ ])*${af1}"

t04="[+-]?${af1}([,]${grp})*([.](${grp}[,])*${af1})?"
t05="[+-]?${af1}([,]${grp})*([.]${af0})?"
t06="[+-]?${af0}[.](${grp}[,])*${af1}"

t07="[+-]?${af1}([.]${grp})*([,](${grp}[.])*${af1})?"
t08="[+-]?${af1}([.]${grp})*([,]${af0})?"
t09="[+-]?${af0}[,](${grp}[.])*${af1}"

t10="[+-]?${dig}*[,.]${dig}+"
t11="[+-]?${dig}+[,.]${dig}*"
t12="[+-]?${dig}+"

s01="${t01}|${t02}|${t03}"
s02="${t04}|${t05}|${t06}"
s03="${t07}|${t08}|${t09}"
s04="${t10}|${t11}|${t12}"

reg="${s01}|${s02}|${s03}|${s04}"

echo "$reg"

sed -E -e "s/${reg}/<&>/g"
```

You can find all this code (and updates) [here](https://github.com/mojadita/so/tree/master/regex/regex-for-custom-decimal-and-thousand-separator).

Comment: I am not using `space` as `Decimal Indicator`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know and that is not valid. I've corrected it

Comment: So then my comment and yours are also uneeded.  Let's erase them.  But that doesn't change my answer, that assumed in the first case that spaces where not group separators (they introduce serious ambiguities on the partins, as I notice there)

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will match all the cases from your example:

```
^[+]?(?:\d{1,3}(?:([,. ])\d{3})*|\d+)?(?:[,.]\d+?){0,1}$
```

The last part (?:[,.]?\d+?){0,1}, makes the matching of the decimal part optional.

Comment: This is matching `1,234.567 890,00.123456,789` not sure that should be valid number.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the infinite repetition of the last part. It's fixed now.

Comment: It's always matching [`1,234.567 890,123 456,789`](https://regex101.co/r/0dLyGE/1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
123.4567
123,4567
123 4567
```

are not valid, you can use:

```
^[+-]?(?:(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d\d)?|(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*|\d+)(?:,\d\d)?|(?:\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*|\d+)(?:[,.]\d\d)?)$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/7vFjhr/4)

Comment: This does not match `1234` or `1234.56`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61730785/13123836)

Comment: Great job! By looking at the regex pattern, I can see that it should match 2 decimal points because of `\d\d` at the end but it accepts up to 3 decimal points and I can't understand why. Do you have any idea? [see this.](https://regex101.com/r/7vFjhr/3) Edit: This happens only if the thousands separator is `space`. But I still can't understand why it happens.

Comment: @Asocia: We must separate the regex in 3 parts, depending on the thousand separator comma, dot or space with the decimal separator allowed for each thousand separator. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```regex
^[+]?(?:\d{1,3}(?:(,|.| )\d{3})*|\d+)?((?<!,\d{3})(,\d+)|(?<!\.\d{3})(\.\d+))?$
```

[Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9tQxa/1)

Comment: You have some invalid matches like `1,123.123 123.123 123,123.123`: https://regex101.com/r/o9tQxa/2

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I modified OP's regex and decided to leave the thousands part as is since he claims it works for his inputs.